# cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'Z'

Tags: python, file, load, pickle

I am trying to read a pickle file "pcadata.pkl" using cPickle, this file i got from github but i am not able to load the file. Same ways when i try to open a file which i created i'm successfully able to load its data. Then why am i not able to open pcadata.pkl file.
Code which i am using for opening loading file:

```
import pprint
import cPickle

pkl_file = open('pcadata.pkl', 'r')

data1 = cPickle.load(pkl_file)
pprint.pprint(data1)

data2 = cPickle.load(pkl_file)
pprint.pprint(data2)

pkl_file.close()
```

Error what i m getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\sklearnproject\OpenPickle.py", line 12, in <module>
data1 = cPickle.load(pkl_file)
cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'Z'.
```